# http.post return 307 error code in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using http client for flutter network call.

1. My request working on postman getting response properly,
2. But while trying with http.post it returns error code 307-Temporary Redirect,

Method Body:

```
static Future<http.Response> httpPost(
  Map postParam, String serviceURL) async {
Map tempParam = {"id": "username", "pwd": "password"};
var param = json.encode(tempParam);
serviceURL = "http:xxxx/Login/Login";

// temp check
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
};
await http.post(serviceURL, headers: headers, body: param).then((response) {
  return response;
});
}
```

Also, the same code returns a proper response to other requests and URLs.
First I trying with chopper client but had same issue.

I am unable to detect that issue from my end of from server-side.

Any help/hint will be helpful

Answer (score 12):

Try to put a slash `/` at the end of the `serviceUrl`. So, serviceUrl is `serviceURL = "http:xxxx/Login/Login/"` instead of `serviceURL = "http:xxxx/Login/Login"`.

This works for me.

Comment: this one solved my 2 hours of searching for a solution. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a way to **follow redirect**.

Maybe postman is doing that.

Read this >> 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClientRequest/followRedirects.html

Can you try with using `get` instead of `post`? At least to try and see what happend

In the documentation said:

```
Automatic redirect will only happen for "GET" and "HEAD" requests
only for the status codes 

HttpStatus.movedPermanently (301), 
HttpStatus.found (302), 
HttpStatus.movedTemporarily (302, alias for HttpStatus.found), 
HttpStatus.seeOther (303),
HttpStatus.temporaryRedirect (307)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Abel's answer above is correct but I had to switch from using:

`Uri url = Uri.https(defaultUri, path);`

to

`Uri url = Uri.parse('https://todo-fastapi-flutter.herokuapp.com/plan/');`

to get that last `/` after `plan`.

The first way kept dropping it so I was getting 307 errors.

flutter.dev shows a full example:

```
Future<http.Response> createAlbum(String title) {
  return http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'title': title,
    }),
  );
}
```

here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data#2-sending-data-to-server

Answer (score 0):

keeping https instead of http in the URL it is helping me.

Answer (score 0):

For Dio Http Client, use Dio Option follow redirect as True

```
getDioOption(){
return BaseOptions(connectTimeout: 30, receiveTimeout: 30,
followRedirects: true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting / at the end of the URL worked for me.

Example:
https://api.com/v1/book/list gives me a temporary redirect error;
while,
https://api.com/v1/book/list/ worked. (/ at the end)